# Что в этих обозначениях 0.2717D+05 - "D"?

Tags: числа

Есть численная информация, поданная в таком виде

```
-0.2717D+05  -0.2277D+04   0.2202D+05   0.1657D+03  -0.7041D+01   0.1479D+03
```

Например, для контекста, вот [здесь](http://cmiss.bioeng.auckland.ac.nz/development/examples/5/55/552/5521/output/rs6000-aix/cm64-debug/cmiss_test.log.retain) такое употребляется.

**Вопрос. Что в этих обозначениях - "D"? Это 10 в какой-то степени? Или нет?**

Знаю, вопрос очень глупый, но раньше никогда не приходилось работать с численными данными, поданными в таком виде, так что не кидайтесь тапочками, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-0.2717D+05 = -0.2717 * 10^5 = -27170
```

D - **D**ouble Precision

Comment: Спасибо! А чем это отличается от -0.2717Е+05? Где используют D, а где Е?

Comment: @Unknown http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~hile/fortran/fort3.htm